Wireless USB extender
Background
A USB 3.0 C webcam streams 4K at 60Hz and 30Hz. Looking to transmit the signal from the webcam to a laptop, without cables. In effect, I'm trying to find hardware for the red boxes in the following diagram:

Requirements

USB C 3.0
5 Gbps bandwidth
Stream 4K @ 60 Hz (or 4K @ 30 Hz)
5 meter signal transmission
Plug-and-play (Windows, Linux, macOS)

Questions
What company makes such wireless USB extensions?
What other possibilities may also work (e.g., USB to wireless Ethernet)?
Solutions
Ideas that give the general idea, but may not be suitable:

j5create -- low resolution, includes mic


Does it have to be 5 Gbps? A 4K/60 Hz video stream can probably be compressed down to something like 100 Mbps with minimal loss in visual fidelity; for example, 4K Blu-Rays run at 92-144 Mbps. For reference, the latest Wi-Fi 7 spec maxes out at 2882 Mbps to a single client; you'd probably be looking at something pretty exotic for a reliable 5 Gbps. Also, does it have to be USB? Support for IP cameras is pretty good these days, and it'd probably be more reliable/cheaper.

I'd like to keep the same camera, which is USB-based. If there's a black box to convert from USB to Ethernet and then go wireless Ethernet back to USB, that would work. Yes, 5 Gbps is required because the stream isn't compressed. Unless there's a hardware solution for that, too?

What camera are you using? 5 Gbps is the theoretical maximum of USB 3.0, it's unlikely the stream is actually using that much.

The camera is linked in the question: Elgato Facecam Pro.

Sorry, missed it since it's just a link.

No exact fit exists, but there are good alternatives
I want to preface this by expressing that it is probably possible, given current technology, to build such a device with enough engineering effort. Yes, 60 GHz wireless transmission has existed for a while, and 802.11ay will probably be adopted in the coming years. You can absolutely push 20-40 Gb/s over the air for 5 meters, probably with low enough latency to be transparent to most USB devices. Indeed, we had Wireless USB over a decade ago doing 480 Mb/s—but that's been deprecated for years on the few platforms that did see decent support.
However, because this is Hardware Recs and not Electrical Engineering, I'm only here to evaluate what actually exists on the market. And right now, there is no fully transparent device where you plug in USB on both ends and it just works.
So, here's what we've got:
j5create JVW120 Wireless Extender for USB Cameras / Microphones / Speakers - $141

I know you're aware of this solution already, but in terms of a plug-and-play solution, this is the closest you're going to get. Plug your Elgato in on one end, get a USB webcam on the other end. No, it won't do 4K@60 Hz, only 4K@30 Hz or 1080p@60 Hz. Yes, it'll probably work. No, you probably won't get to use all the fancy Elgato software to control your webcam.
Why? Well, because it's not actually sending USB packets; it's taking the video stream, compressing it using MJPEG or H.264, sending that its own wireless connection, and then emulating a webcam on the other end. It's simple and effective, but it's not really different from using an IP camera. Which begs the question: why not just make your own IP camera?
Make your own IP camera with the Elgato Facecam Pro
With a computer and some software, you can turn
pretty much any camera into an IP camera. There's a number of different protocols which you could use for video transmission, including RTMP, SRT, WebRTC, RTSP, or even just yeeting the raw video stream over the network—most of which are supported by OBS. However, NDI (Network Device Interface) is probably a solid choice; it's designed for this sort of application, includes camera controls, and is reasonably widely supported; all major OSs have some level of support, along with OBS, and the NDI group publishes plenty of cross-platform tools as well.
All we need to worry about is the source/transmission side. In terms of hardware/software, I'd recommend the following:

OBSBOT UVC to NDI Adapter - $299. It's expensive, and doesn't have build-in Wi-Fi, so you'd still need to connect it to a small access point. However, it's robust and comes with support.
Dicaffeine with a computer of your choice, such as a Raspberry Pi. Really any computer running Raspbian/Ubuntu with a good wireless adapter should be sufficient, but the Pi is notable for its low cost and solid hardware.

Just use your phone
I won't deny that the Elgato Facecam Pro is a pretty solid camera—even if it doesn't compete with dedicated DSLR/mirrorless cameras at a similar price point, it's a nice plug and play solution for a USB webcam. However, it's not a nice plug-and-play solution for a wireless camera. If you're going to go through the expense and pain of making it one, maybe it's time to reevaluate if it's the right solution.
Phones these days have extremely good cameras, and are extremely cheap thanks to their huge economies of scale. They also tend to come with good onboard processors capable of high-bitrate video processing and encoding, and pretty nice Wi-Fi chips. A used iPhone 14 (unlocked, no less) is about the same cost as the Facecam Pro, and there are tons of apps for using your phone as a camera. Hell, Apple even includes a built-in one if you happen to be using a Mac, and Elgato will happily sell you one for $8 if you hate the other free/fremium options out there. Odds are it'll be more reliable than whatever you roll yourself, and look close to (if not quite as good as) the Elgato. Plus, you probably already have a phone you can try it out with.
Hardware recommendation is about picking the right tool for the job. Cost is always a factor—sometimes that means reusing what you have, but sometimes it means buying something different.
